# asynchronous call to return a value?

Tags: javascript, html

I am bulding a table that either shows a play button or a stop button. (and some other stuff)

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
var current = result[i].split("$");
if (CheckRunning(current[0])){
    t = t + "<tr><td><img alt='stop' id='img"+i+"' src='stop.png' onclick='ChangeButton(\"img"+i+"\");'/>";
} else {
    t = t + "<tr><td><img alt='play' id='img"+i+"' src='play.png' onclick='ChangeButton(\"img"+i+"\");'/>";
}}
```

The problem here is the CheckRunning method. It opens a database which is an asynchron method. I cant simply do a return true/false. So whats the solution? anyway, here is the code for it:

```
  var tabel;
    var running = false;
    function CheckRunning(tabel){
    this.tabel = "tabel"+tabel+"";
    var db = window.openDatabase(this.tabel, "1.0", this.tabel, 1000000);
    db.transaction(checkrunningDB, checkerrorCB);
    console.log(this.running);
    return this.running;
    }

    function checkrunningDB(tx) {
       tx.executeSql('SELECT max(id), sluttime FROM '+this.tabel, [], checkrunningSuccess, checkerrorCB);
    }

    function checkrunningSuccess(tx, results) {
        if (results.rows.item(0).sluttime != null){
            this.running = false;
        } else{
            this.running = true;
        }
    }
    function checkerrorCB(err) {
         this.running = false;
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a callback function to `CheckRunning`:

```
CheckRunning(current[0], function(isRunning){...})
...
function CheckRunning(tabel, callback)
{
    var isRunning = null; // we don't know yet
    ....
    callback(isRunning);
}
```

It's similar to your `tx.executeSql` function which takes checkRunningSuccess as a callback. In that case the function name is hard coded as checkRunningSuccess, you could do the same in checkRunning.

---

By the way, if this is a public webapp running SQL queries makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean and how that is going to help me. If i do a callback or not, the code will still be executed before immediatly

Comment: @AbdullahGheith No, it won't. `checkrunningSuccess` is called when you have the result, right? So until you call your callback with the result no code will be executed. You need to put all your code that depends on `isRunning` into the callback. If you don't want to use a callback you might be able to modify the `executeSql` function to use a synchronous ajax call. Once you run the call asynchronously and use a callback - which you do in the code above - there's no way to delay return a value until it's available.

Comment: I kinda understand where you are going. The problem is that i dont recieve the result before checkRunningSuccess. so how will it know when my success is? I've done this, and it is still the same: http://pastebin.com/5uSP4sLm (Calling cr() from my button)

Comment: @AbdullahGheith You need to call `callback(this.running);` in `checkrunningSuccess`. That's when you know the result of your query. If you can't pass the callback to that function directly you can store it as a global variable.